# "LocalSystem" and Linux Samba Network share access, IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation

Tags: linux, dns, samba, smb, network-share

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace CreateDirectoryTest {
    internal class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            if (!args.Any()) {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Usage: CreateDirectoryTest.exe {paths}");
            }
            foreach (var arg in args) {
                try {
                    Console.WriteLine("Need to create the folder? " + arg + " (y/n)");
                    var input = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (input != null && input.Equals("n")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(arg);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error Creating directory: " + arg);
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code creates an executable CreateDirectoryTest.exe and has been tested on win 2016 server and win 10 desktop machines respectively.
eg: `CreateDirectoryTest.exe \\\ip-address\data\testFolder`
\\ip-address\data\testFolder is a network share on a Linux filesystem and SMB protocol is been used for the communication.

The above process was executed under administrator and system (NT Authority/ SYSTEM) users respectively on both operating systems, but this fails on win 2016 server for the system user execution scenario with the following error:

```
Error Creating directory: \\ip-address\data\testFolder
System.IO.IOException: The specified server cannot perform the requested operation.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at CreateDirectoryTest.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Could someone please suggest a solution to resolve this issue on win server 2016?

[image: process in win server 2016]

Note: Windows 2016 server is not registered in the domain, while Windows 10 is been registered and has a domain name

Comment: I have seen in the Samba documentation that the LocalSystem account uses domain computer name for the authentication, in my scenario the Win2016 server is not in domain, so how to succeed in case of servers not in domain, anyone got any idea?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? In my case I'm able to access the SAMBA share from the command line or a console application, but not from an IIS Site. I'm using Windows Server 2019 Standard and IIS 10.0. Any suggestions on how to solve this?